# Slow average function in BaseX

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

I'm totally new to XML and consequently XQuery.  I have a large XML file (~30 GB) which I have loaded into a Basex Database.  My problem is that the average function is taking a very long time to run.

Sample XML file:

```
<a>
 <b Id="1" Result="1"/>
 <b Id="2" Result="2"/>
 <b Id="1" Result="5"/>
 <b Id="1" Result="510"/>
</a>
```

I want the average Result for Id = 1.  When I run,

```
for $x in //a/b
where $x/@Id="1"
return $x/@Result
```

The query takes roughly 1-2 seconds.  Not to bad.  However, when I attempt to obtain the average the query never ends (I've let it run for 10min)

```
avg(
for $x in //a/b
where $x/@Id="1"
return $x/@Result    
)
```

What is going on?

Please let me know if I can provide additional information which will facilitate answers.

Comment: This looks like the attribute index is not used any more and a sequential scan is performed. What BaseX version are you using? Please also have a look at the query info. For both queries, something like `db:attribute` should occur in the optimized query.

Answer (score 0):

Try avg(//a/b[@Id="1"]/@Result).  A predicate is more efficient than a where clause.

Comment: thanks for the advice, however, this will not help.  The query nested inside the avg() runs quickly even with the where clause.  The problem is taking the average itself take a long time.

Comment: Also, this is not true in general. Often, the BaseX optimizer rewrites the where clause into a predicate.